# Array function for calculating Option prices

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to implement my first BS option model in Python.Instead of passing one Underlying price at a time however, I would like to pass an array. Here's the code and the error message:

```
xS=np.arange(10,110,10)

C=np.maximum(xS-K,0)

def bsm_call(S,K,T,r,sigma):

    d1=[(log(S/K) + 0.5 * pow(sigma,2)*T)/(sigma*pow(T,0.5)) for S in xS ] 

    d2=[d1-sigma*pow(T,0.5)]

    vC=[S * stats.norm.cdf(d1,0,1) - K * exp(-r*T) * stats.norm.cdf(d2,0,1)]

    return np.array(vC)

extC=bsm_call(xS,K,T,r,sigma)
```

generates: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'float'

Not sure what this means, but I think it doesn't like the way I'm passing the xS array. So just to test, I tried:

```
def test(S,K,T,r,sigma):    
    d1=[(log(S/K) + 0.5 * pow(sigma,2)*T)/(sigma*pow(T,0.5)) for S in xS ] 
    return np.array(d1)

test1=test(xS,K,T,r,sigma)
print(test1)
```

This gave me some values for d1 (not sure if they are correct....but at-least the code worked). So, encouraged by this, I tried adding a second line:

```
def test(S,K,T,r,sigma):    
    d1=[(log(S/K) + 0.5 * pow(sigma,2)*T)/(sigma*pow(T,0.5)) for S in xS ] 
    d2=[d1-sigma*pow(T,0.5) for S in xS]
    return np.array(d1+d2)

test1=test(xS,K,T,r,sigma)
print(test1)
```

The error message is now:
[image]

I'm trying to avoid looping through the xS array "directly". Obviously, not nuanced enough in Python to to do it....would appreciate some suggestions. Thanks,C

Answer (score 0):

```
d1=[(log(S/K) + 0.5 * pow(sigma,2)*T)/(sigma*pow(T,0.5)) for S in xS ]
```

`d1` is a simple Python list.

```
d2=[d1-sigma*pow(T,0.5) for S in xS]
```

Here, you're trying to subtract a float value from an entire list, and do it `len(xS)` times.  What functionality do you think you should get from this?  It's certainly not legal.

You can subtract a float from a NumPy array, but not from a list.

Comment: thanks for your comments. Trial and error at this time, without fully knowing all the nuances of Python. Ultimately, I'm just trying to pass the entire index of Stock prices into the BS equation and get an array of BS prices.

Comment: Then you need to use an array, not a list.  Try `np.array(d1)` rather than merely `d1`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the suggestion from @Prune...coudln't get the syntax to work. So i tried this -

```
def bsm_call(S,K,T,r,sigma):
    d1=(log(S/K) + 0.5 * pow(sigma,2)*T)/(sigma*pow(T,0.5))
    d2=d1-sigma*pow(T,0.5)
    vC=S * stats.norm.cdf(d1,0,1) - K * exp(-r*T) * stats.norm.cdf(d2,0,1)
    return vC



extC=[]
for i in xS:  
   #print(i)
   extC.append(bsm_call(i,K,T,r,sigma))
   print(i)
print(extC)
```

and was able to pass elements of the stock price array into the BS call function. I was trying to do it one step...but I guess this works for now.